# Expose RDBMS (SQLite) data as SPARQL endpoint

Tags: sqlite, sparql, jena, r2rml

I am working on a demo for which I need to expose some data stored in the `SQLite DB` file as a `SPARQL` endpoint that can be queried. This doesn't have to be fancy at the moment just a way to expose static data as the `RDF` is fine for me.

I am wondering if anyone knows how to achieve this using any Open source or free tools available.

I understand that I might have to write `r2rml` mapping file and other configurations, however I am unable to find a way to do the same. I hear `Apache Jena` can do the trick, however can't find a good example on how to achieve this.

Does someone knows a good tutorial that shows how this can be achieved.

Comment: there are r2rml tools that can convert your data to RDF which you can then load e.g. via Jena, RDF4J or any other triple store accessible via HTTP. You could also just use RML, description here: https://rml.io/

Answer (score 1):

After looking at various options, i found http://d2rq.org/ as the most easiest way to expose my RDBMS data as SPARQL endpoit.

Please follow the documentation on the portal, which is very generous on explaining how this can be achieved.